# Python netmiko failing to install - problem with pynacl

Tags: python, ubuntu

Hope you can help. I am a novice in respect of Ubuntu so apologies in advance.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and am trying to install netmiko in python3.5.2

I am hitting a problem with pynacl which is causing the install to fail. The type of error messages I am getting are as follows:

> /tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c: In function 'crypto_hash_sha256.constprop':
> /tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c:205:31: warning: iteration 64 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
> state->buf[r + i] = in[i];
> ^
> /tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c:204:9: note: containing loop
> for (i = 0; i < inlen; i++) {
> ^

```
CC       stream2.o
CCLD     stream2
```

/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c: In function 'crypto_hash_sha256.constprop':
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c:205:31: warning: iteration 64 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
state->buf[r + i] = in[i];
^

/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/src/libsodium/crypto_hash/sha256/cp/hash_sha256_cp.c:204:9: note: containing loop
for (i = 0; i < inlen; i++) {
^

/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19878 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19885 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box2
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19892 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box7
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19899 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box8
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19906 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box_easy
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19913 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1

FAIL: box_easy2
/tmp/pip-install-d4reycz5/pynacl/src/libsodium/build-aux/test-driver: line 107: 19920 Illegal instruction     (core dumped) "$@" > $log_file 2>&1
FAIL: box_seal

> 

I believe I have all the necessary modules eg libsodium etc.
Look forward to hearing from you.

Phil

Comment: This is not a programming question, rather one of usage/installation and/or a bug report. As a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask], for example you don't even tell us what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. It appears that Netmiko is only support on Python3.6 and above.

Have installed Python3.8.5 and it appears to be working.